# A system of three planes passing through the origin has always the same result?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given any system of three planes in a three-dumensional space, such that all of them pass through the origin, do all the cases have the same result of the system, that is the null vector?

Comment: By "result of the system" do you mean the intersection of the planes?  No.  Consider three planes that all include the $x$ axis.

Comment: Does every system of three homogeneous equations in three unknowns only have the trivial solution? Is every $3\times3$ matrix nonsingular?

Comment: I didn't specified many things, so i apologize about that. @RobertIsrael you were correct on your interpretation as (at)amd were. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all three planes are identical, then this plane is the intersection. If not, then the intersection of two of the planes is a straight line. If the third plane also contains this straight line, then this straight line is the intersection. If not, then the intersection is just the origin (the "null vector").